# Proguard method optimization

Tags: java, android, methods, proguard

When using Proguard some methods bodies are replaced by this:

```
public void someMethod(int paramInt1, int paramInt2, boolean paramBoolean, String paramString){

 // Byte code:
    //   0: aload_1
    //   1: invokeinterface getItemId : ()I
    //   6: istore_2
    //   7: iload_2
    //   8: ldc_w 2131296320
    //   11: if_icmpne -> 31
    //   14: aload_0
    //   15: new android/content/Intent
    //   18: dup
    //   19: aload_0
    //   20: ldc_w com/example/turtle/Activity
    //   23: invokespecial <init> : (Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    //   26: invokevirtual startActivity : (Landroid/content/Intent;)V
    //   29: iconst_1
    //   30: ireturn
    //   31: iload_2
    //   32: ldc_w 2131296310
    //   35: if_icmpne -> 95
    //   38: aload_0
    //   39: getfield O : Landroid/view/View;
    //   42: ldc_w 'Layout Changed'
    //   ...


}
```

while most of them have something like this:

```
public void anotherMethod(){

    this.W.setColor(i);
    this.X.setTextColor(i);
    this.Y.setColor(i);
    this.Z.setColor(i);
    b.c.a.x0.a a1 = new b.c.a.x0.a();
    a1.setDuration(100);
    a.u.m.a((ViewGroup)this.a0, (a.u.i)a1);
    if (this.U) {
      this.a0.removeView((View)this.h0);
      linearLayout = this.a0;
      a2 = this.g0;
    } else {
      this.a0.removeView((View)this.b0);
      this.a0.removeView((View)this.d0);
      linearLayout = this.a0;
      a2 = this.e0;
    } 

}
```

Why aren't they all like the first sample code? And is there a way to force Proguard to optimize methods like in the the first sample code?

Im using dex2jar to decompile and jd-gui to view it.

Any insight is appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in what ProGuard does between these two methods.

The difference is in the tool you're using to *read* ProGuard's output: what bytecode it can and can't decompile to make it look like normal Java source.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Im using dex2jar to decompile and jd-gui to view it. But if there is no difference why one can be decompiled but the other can't?

Comment: Some bytecode can be turned into Java.  Some can't.  Smarter decompilers can turn more things into Java.  It just depends on what _exactly_ the bytecode looks like when ProGuard is done with it.

Comment: I get that some code can't be decompile while others can. And that's exactly what I want to know. How to make Proguard yield the bytecode that can't be decompiled easily? that's what I'm after. Do I have to structure my methods in a specific way?

Comment: There is _no way_ to do that in general.